# Issue when added when forEach, react es6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wrote a loop and its working fine

```
this.props.items.map((item, key) => (
    ( item.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf('a'.toLowerCase())  )?
          <Task key={item._id} id={item.adsets_id} i={key} item={item} date_from={this.state.date_from} date_to={this.state.date_to} campaign_name={this.state.campaign_name} adset_name={this.state.adset_name} />
          :
          <tr><td colSpan={15}>&nbsp;</td></tr>
 )
)
```

and later i have added `forEach` but result getting empty

```
this.props.items.map((item, key) => (
    this.props.campaign_name.split(",").forEach(function(entry) {
      (  item.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf('a'.toLowerCase())  )?
          <Task key={item._id} id={item.adsets_id} i={key} item={item} date_from={this.state.date_from} date_to={this.state.date_to} campaign_name={this.state.campaign_name} adset_name={this.state.adset_name} />
      :
      <tr><td colSpan={15}>&nbsp;</td></tr>

    }.bind(this))
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, forEach doesn't return anything. It only loops and executes instructions inside loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Replacing it with `map` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

## forEach()

Iterate through the given list and perform the given task

---

## map()

Iterates through the list and **transform** each element